# What happens with energy levels when considering electrostatic interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, electrons

Imagine a many-electron system. If we consider all atoms (or just electrons) to be equal, then there is a certain degeneracy to the energy levels these electrons occupy. To lift it, one can choose to include the inter-electron electrostatic interaction between the electrons. The system becomes more complicated to calculate when doing this, obviously.

My questions are:

1. is there a certain name for this degeneracy that is lifted?
2. what quantum numbers are affected/changed/newly introduced by this?
3. is this relevant when only considering a single atom with many electrons, e.g. Lithium (which is very Hydrogen-like, so still somewhat solvable numerically)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure why you think we consider all the electrons to be equal. Typically we'd start with a mean field calculation and this gives us hydrogenic $1s$, $2s$, etc orbitals that we fill two electrons at a time. Then we'd use a configuration interaction calculation to bring in the pair repulsion. The CI calculation mixes up the hydrogenic orbitals so there are no distinct atomic orbitals any more, just a single multi-electron wavefunction.

Comment: Maybe it helps when I quote the question directly (I didn't want to just copy and paste it). It says: What degeneracy is lifted in many-electron systems when considering inter-electron electrostatic interaction?

Also, why wouldn't we consider electrons to be equal? They occupy different orbitals, sure, but their intrinsic properties are identical, no?

Comment: I suspect the question is getting at the fact the $s$ and $p$ orbitals have the same energy in a hydrogen atom but different energies in multielectron atoms. Re electrons: obviously all electrons are identical, but they can still have different energies, which they obviously do in multielectron atoms.

Comment: "If we consider all electrons to be equal, then there is a certain degeneracy to the energy levels these electrons occupy" ... what? This is false in general. Take, say, two electrons in a 1D infinite square well, so each single-electron orbital is nondegenerate. After imposing fermionic statistics, the many-body eigenstates are also nondegenerate, regardless of whether you add interactions or  not.

Comment: Regarding the specific text of the question as in your last comment, though, it's hard to know for sure without knowing the specific text of the question and the surrounding context. John Rennie's suggestion of the $s$-$p$ split is a valid candidate, but it is important to note that this is exclusively a mean-field property driven by shielding of the nuclear potential, and that it is therefore often left out of the term "many-body" (which is reserved for beyond-Hartree-Fock properties). Whether your text would consider that as an answer or not will therefore depend on the context.